# Pylint Exception on Win7/Python 3.2: return u''

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

After installing Pylint 1.5.4 on under Windows 7 / Python 3.2.5 (pip install pylint), I get the following exception when trying to invoke:

```
b:\Sandbox\PyLoad>pylint PyLoad.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python32\lib\site-packages\astroid\builder.py", line 172, in _data_build
    node = _parse(data + '\n')
  File "c:\python32\lib\site-packages\astroid\builder.py", line 40, in _parse
    return compile(string, "<string>", 'exec', _ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<string>", line 12
    return u''
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python32\lib\runpy.py", line 161, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python32\lib\runpy.py", line 74, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python32\Scripts\pylint.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python32\lib\site-packages\pylint\__init__.py", line 22, in run_pylint
    from pylint.lint import Run
  File "c:\python32\lib\site-packages\pylint\lint.py", line 44, in <module>
    import astroid
  File "c:\python32\lib\site-packages\astroid\__init__.py", line 136, in <module>
    __import__(module[:-3])
  File "c:\python32\lib\site-packages\astroid\brain\brain_builtin_inference.py", line 76, in <module>
    'str': partial(_extend_str, rvalue="''")})
  File "c:\python32\lib\site-packages\astroid\brain\brain_builtin_inference.py", line 72, in extend_builtins
    transform(builtin_ast[class_name])
  File "c:\python32\lib\site-packages\astroid\brain\brain_builtin_inference.py", line 63, in _extend_str
    fake = AstroidBuilder(MANAGER).string_build(code)['whatever']
  File "c:\python32\lib\site-packages\astroid\builder.py", line 146, in string_build
    module = self._data_build(data, modname, path)
  File "c:\python32\lib\site-packages\astroid\builder.py", line 174, in _data_build
    raise exceptions.AstroidBuildingException(exc)
astroid.exceptions.AstroidBuildingException: invalid syntax (<string>, line 12)
```

It looks like something is trying to return a unicode string using Python 2 syntax, but this is Python 3.

In astroid's builder.py, _data_build is being called with the string:

```
class whatever(object):
    def join(self, iterable):
        return b''
    def replace(self, old, new, count=None):
        return b''
    def format(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return b''
    def encode(self, encoding='ascii', errors=None):
        return ''
    def decode(self, encoding='ascii', errors=None):
        return u''
           .
           .
           .
```

I assume this **return u''** is causing the problem.

Anyone seen this, and have a solution?

Comment: Python 3.0 through 3.2 don't support the old syntax for unicode literals. Python 3.3 [brought the syntax back](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/) (to make porting Python 2 code easier). Can you upgrade your Python version to a newer one? It sounds like your version of PyLint may require either an older (2.7) or a newer (3.3+) version.

Comment: Because of what @Blckknght said it's quite hard to write Python2/3 compatible code with < 3.3. That's why many tools (even pip or coverage.py) don't support it anymore.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue.  Pylint uses astroid, which supports 3.3+.  Upgrading to 3.5 fixed the problem.